# How to position Fancybox horizontal line lower

Tags: fancybox, line, caption

I wonder if it's possible to have the horizontal line that is located above the caption positioned lower? The bottom end of some of my images now are seen below that line.

[example](https://byjohan.se/Bootstrap/metal-sculptures-pure.html#gallery-1)

Click the first thumbnail from the left and when it opens up you'll see that part of it is below the horizontal line.

As mentioned in the comments below this seems to only apply to Chrome on desktop. For FF on desktop it works as it should, and also for Chrome and Samsung Browser on my tablet.

Comment: Can you add an image example?

Comment: Just play with CSS, add paddings/marging here and there till you are satisfied (it is hard to give more specific answer without seeing some mockup or smth)

Comment: Weird, I as you can see added an example but when opening that link in FF the whole image is way over the line but still, when opening it in Chrome part of the image is below that same line... So, it seems FF and Chrome rendes it differently.